# Smoother access to files on FTP Server

Tags: ftp, images, nautilus, read, icons

I use Nautilus on Ubuntu 18.04.3 to access ftp server. But if I select any files, it opens in the browser first, then gets downloaded in the download folder and then I have to open that downloaded file.

Is it possible that when I select a file to open it, it opens in the suitable application software (may be it could download a copy of the file in the temp folder). Also, can the icons be downloaded (by itself) for the type of file. For example, if I have photos on my ftp server, I would like to see those photos as icons as it does for images on the local device.

If the file is edited may be it could offer us to **Save as** another file, or if we have write access it could transfer the edited file to the ftp server.

Issue: **Is it possible to achieve this in Nautilus or in some other software?**

Comment: May be a fuse ftp file-system. However snapshots are harder. They need to be downloaded to make the thumb nail. Or They need server support to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you mentioned except the image previews is implemented in the FTP client [filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) which is available in the Ubuntu repositories. Another option could be a FUSE filesystem like [curlftpfs](https://www.hiroom2.com/2018/05/05/ubuntu-1804-curlftpfs-en/), where you could browse to your chosen ftp mount point and use nautilus, where it would work like any other folder.